# Татевик Азарян. Женщина. Не склоняется ведь?

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Армянские женские фамилии не склоняются. А имена? Склоняюсь к тому, что тоже нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Имя Татевик не склоняется.**
Насколько знаю, это имя означает "ангел" - и может принадлежать и мужчине (намного реже). Но когда принадлежит женщине - несклоняемо.

Короче, не надо ни к чему "склоняться". В русском языке просто нет парадигмы (образца, схемы) для склонения подобных имен. И не принципиально то, что имя армянское, первопричина - в том, что оно оканчивается на твердый согласный.

Принадлежащие женщинам, но оканчивающиеся на согласный, ИМЕНА СОБСТВЕННЫЕ не склоняются. Исключения - имена третьего склонения на мягкий согласный.

(+)=======

Информация к размышлению. В сети есть примеры, вот один такой.

> Однако Игорь внезапно ухитрился изменить Татевик с ее же подругой -

Очень бы хотелось узнать, по какой схеме склонения тут может быть образован дательный падеж.

Comment: Отличный ответ! Мне вот только интересно стало, действительно ли нужно закрыть придаточное с НО (конец предпоследней строчки у вас).

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Да, нужно. Спасибо. В качестве оправдания - Вы поймали момент незаконченной правки.

Comment: Я предположил, что запятая перед НЕ может быть лишней. А теперь кажется, что надо одну из них оставить, если хоть одна нужна. Буду благодарен, если укажете правило. И ещё смущает ТО в *не принципиально, то что имя армянское.*

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  *И ещё смущает ТО в не принципиально, то что имя армянское* - исправил.  Про "правило" - уже не могу, фразу изменил, какой она раньше была - о том уже не хочется вспоминать. вроде бы там был обычный причастный оборот.

Comment: Перед НЕ запятая точно не нужна. Я бы и перед ИМЕНАМИ убрал, ведь причастный оборот стоит перед.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец - я сделал законченный вариант, можете смело править все, что считаете нужным (пунктуацию и проч.), мне отвлекли, сейчас не до этого. (+++) Перед "именами собственными" - по другим мотивам. Я "обособил" противительную конструкцию "но оканчивающиеся на согласный". Без этого плохо воспринимается.

Comment: [Вот](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=100#pp100), нашёл: п. 6. Согласно Розенталю тут не нужна и другая запятая, если я правильно понимаю.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой - извините, позже посмотрю. Я "в поход" собрался.

Comment: Да, конечно, давайте потом. Удачи!)))

Answer (score 0):

Правильно, не склоняется и имя.

Вот пример из Нацкорпуса с похожими именами (кончающимися на К, там родительный падеж):

> Передай привет тете Габо, Гайку и детям. Привет также **Астхик и Арусяк.** Им также я обещал написать письмо, но до сих пор не написал. *[Анастас Микоян. Так было (1971-1974)]*

Answer (score -2):

Не знаю, можно ли относить армян к иностранцам, ведь Армения входила в состав СССР, но согласно Розенталю (§ 151. Склонение некоторых имен и фамилий) **иностранные имена на согласный звук склоняются независимо от того, употребляются ли они самостоятельно или вместе с фамилией**, например: романы Жюля Верна (не «Жюль Верна»), рассказы Марка Твена, пьесы Джона Бойнтона Пристли, сказки Ханса Кристиана Андерсена, книга Пьера-Анри Симона. Частичные отступления наблюдаются при двойных французских именах, например: философские воззрения Жан-Жака Руссо, вечер памяти Жан-Ришара Блока (первое имя не склоняется, см. § 13, п. 3).

Comment: *можно ли относить армян к иностранцам* - это совершенно не принципиально.  А правило ваше применимо к именам собственным МУЖЧИН. А вопрос о женском имени Татевик.

Comment: Очень жаль. В таком случае в скором времени с позором удалю свой ответ.